# Using of MPI Barrier lead to fatal error

Tags: mpi

I get a strange behavior of my simple MPI program. I spent time to find an answer myself, but I can't. I red some questions here, like [OpenMPI MPI_Barrier problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182045/openmpi-mpi-barrier-problems), [MPI_SEND stops working after MPI_BARRIER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466119/mpi-send-stops-working-after-mpi-barrier), [Using MPI_Bcast for MPI communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864075/using-mpi-bcast-for-mpi-communication). I red MPI tutorial on [mpitutorial](http://mpitutorial.com/).
My program just modify array that was broadcasted from root process and then gather modified arrays to one array and print them.
So, the problem is, that when I use code listed below with uncommented MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) I get an error.

```
#include "mpi/mpi.h"
#define N 4

void transform_row(int* row, const int k) {
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    row[i] *= k;
  }
}
const int root = 0;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int rank, ranksize;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ranksize);
  if (rank == root) {
    int* arr = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
      arr[i] = i * i + 1;
    }
    MPI_Bcast(arr, N, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  int* arr = new int[N];
  MPI_Bcast(arr, N, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  //MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  transform_row(arr, rank * 100);
  int* transformed = new int[N * ranksize];
  MPI_Gather(arr, N, MPI_INT, transformed, N, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if (rank == root) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ranksize; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < N ; j++) {
        printf("%i ", transformed[i * N + j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The error comes with number of thread > 1. The error:

Fatal error in PMPI_Barrier: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Barrier(425)...................: MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed

MPIR_Barrier_impl(332)..............: Failure during collective

MPIR_Barrier_impl(327)..............:

MPIR_Barrier(292)...................:

MPIR_Barrier_intra(150).............:

barrier_smp_intra(111)..............:

MPIR_Bcast_impl(1452)...............:

MPIR_Bcast(1476)....................:

MPIR_Bcast_intra(1287)..............:

MPIR_Bcast_binomial(239)............:

MPIC_Recv(353)......................:

MPIDI_CH3U_Request_unpack_uebuf(568): Message truncated; 16 bytes received but buffer size is 1

I understand that some problem with buffer exists, but when I use MPI_buffer_attach to attach big buffer to MPI it don't help.

Seems I need to increase this buffer, but I don't now how to do this.

XXXXXX@XXXXXXXXX:~/test_mpi$ mpirun --version

HYDRA build details:

```
Version:                                 3.2

Release Date:                            Wed Nov 11 22:06:48 CST 2015
```

So help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One issue is `MPI_Bcast()` is invoked twice by the `root` rank, but only once by the other ranks. And then `root` rank uses an uninitialized `arr`.

`MPI_Barrier()` might only hide the problem, but it cannot fix it.

Also, note that if `N` is "large enough", then the second `MPI_Bcast()` invoked by `root` rank will likely hang.

Here is how you can revamp the init/broadcast phase to fix these issues.

```
int* arr = new int[N];
if (rank == root) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i * i + 1;
    }
MPI_Bcast(arr, N, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note in this case, you can simply initialize `arr` on all the ranks so you do not even need to broadcast the array.

As a side note, MPI program typically

```
#include <mpi.h>
```

and then use `mpicc` for the compilation/linking
(this is a wrapper that invoke the real compiler after setting the include/library paths and using the MPI libs)

Comment: You are absolutely right. My thanks for your help with this problem. I was blind for two times bcasting of arr with root process. My shame.

Comment: Anybody needs an extra pair of eyes once in a while, so there is zero need to feel any kind of shame here.

Comment: btw, please consider removing your initial (and incorrect) answer. Thanks !

Comment: Rule of thumb: never put a collective inside a conditional. Yes, there are cases, but if you're a beginning MPI programmer, think twice.